# how to count my comment from mysql

Tags: php, mysqli

how can i include count in my code to count and echo out the total number of comment posted on my page and i want it to update itself. pls help me out. here is the code

```
SELECT * COUNT(id) as count  FROM test WHERE id =id.
```

this is MySQL data

```
id(primary key) | name   | comment       

       1    | john   | some  

       2    | mark   | text      

       3    | David  | text   

       4    | Chris  | text   

       5    | Joel   | other
```

Comment: Do you use a framework ? Do you use vanilla PHP ? We can't help you without some crucial informations... your question is too blurry.

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(id) as counts FROM test `

Answer (score 0):

You need to group your data.  Assuming you want to count how many comments each user has made:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*) as count  FROM test GROUP BY name;
```

You need to select the name and the count so you can output them later.

If you just want to know how many comments there are in the entire table

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count  FROM test
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `FOUND_ROWS()` immediately after query:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE  ...;    
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$count = $db->exec("SELECT count(ID) from test");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Following query will get you the total number of comments in your table

SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_comments FROM comments;

+----------------+
| total_comments |
+----------------+
|             12 |
+----------------+



// This will always give you total_comments = 1 if id exists in table (since id is primary key)
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_comments FROM comments WHERE id = 1;

+----------------+
| total_comments |
+----------------+
|              1 |
+----------------+
```

Refer this [tutorial](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html)

To work on PHP with mysqli, work on this [tutorial](https://www.php.net/mysqli_fetch_assoc)